# Bootstrap navbar menu doesn't drop down when collapsed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, navbar, dropdown, responsive

I've been working on building a responsive site using Bootstrap, and the navbar is giving me issues. Right now I have it set to toggle when the screen size shrinks, and while it does create a button for a dropdown menu, the menu doesn't actually drop down when the button is clicked. I've tried looking through other answers to similar problems and I'm not seeing anything specifically helpful to this issue. I'm using Bootstrap 4 (https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css)

And here is the code for my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">First Last</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent"
      aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
```

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm relatively new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

It's working true and the navbar menu is working truly in bootstrap.

Your Issue is for you aren't importing the bootstrap javascript in your code

your code simple with solved issue:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
 
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
   
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
   
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
   
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

and another example https://jsfiddle.net/Alirezaaraby/j7Lf6mtn/7/

you should import following script at the end of your `<body>` in your HTML code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```